# Views inside UITableViewCell are nil after converting UITableViewController to SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swiftui

I'm in the process of porting a UITableViewController code to SwiftUI. I've created a UIViewControllerRepresentable struct for the same. Everything works as it should except for the below two:

1. There's a UIView and a UILabel inside the UITableViewCell. These two are connected via outlets to the code and they work perfect in UIKit project. However, both of these are nil when accessed via the UIViewControllerRepresentable class in the SwiftUI project. I can access the cell.textLabel, which tells me that the cell has been initialized.

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! DepartmentTVCell
    // Error: The label & cell are nil at runtime
    cell.label.text = departmentsFRC?.object(at: indexPath).name
    cell.view.backgroundColor = .random()
    // Issue: Only the below code works
    cell.textLabel?.text = departmentsFRC?.object(at: indexPath).name
    return cell
}
```

2. The UITableViewController in UIKit project doesn't require registering of the cells, as the prototype cell is connected via storyboard. However, in SwiftUI version, the custom class for the cell works only if it's registered. That's fine but does anyone know why this is the case?

I've uploaded the working project to https://github.com/felixmariaa/PortTVCToSwiftUI. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you define your cell in `Storyboard` there is no need to call `registerCell` func and there is no need to register cell in tableview. Also you should change your `makeUIController` to this that get your VC from storyboard :

```
func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DepartmentTVCRepresentable>) -> DepartmentTVC {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let departmentTVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DepartmentVC") as! DepartmentTVC
        return departmentTVC
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set identifire for View controller storyboard as here I set `DepartmentVC`

Comment: Thanks. It works. Just fyi, looks like you missed deleting departmentTVC.registerCell() in your code.